# Which graphic or graphics card for 4 monitors?

Tags: multiple-monitors

What is the recommended way of getting 4 monitors on my future computer?  Is it best to get 2 graphics card with 2 dvi ports each?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Prior to mainstream adoption of the PCIe bus, configurations of more
>   than two monitors were either achieved with an AGP card with dual
>   video outputs or by using an AGP graphics adapter as the primary
>   device and a conventional PCI graphics adapter as a secondary device.
>   However, given the bandwidth limitations of the older PCI bus[citation
>   needed], such setups were not common, and maximum overall graphics
>   performance could be obtained only by using specialty solutions such
>   as the Matrox G450, which features four outputs from one graphics
>   adapter. Now that computers with two or more PCIe interfaces are
>   popular, middle- and high-end computers are no longer limited to two
>   monitors driven by a single main graphics adapter. If a dual PCIe
>   interface is not available or is otherwise occupied, a standard PCI
>   graphics card can still be used to provide additional video outputs,
>   albeit with performance trade-offs. Specialized
>   application environments such as CAD, day trading of corporate stocks,
>   and software development are increasingly using six or more monitors
>   on one production system.
>
> A quad-monitor Digital Audio Workstation Additional monitors can also
>   be connected to PCs via a USB connection such as DisplayLink.

Seems that it doesn't matter much if it's connected to a PCI Express slot. If it's just a normal PCI (or maybe an AGP) it's recommended to use 2 seperate graphic cards.

---

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-monitor#More_than_two_monitors

---

Also, here's a PCI Express graphic card that support 4 monitors. Don't know how Ubuntu compatibility is though.
http://www.nextag.com/VisionTek-Radeon-HD5570-PCIe-827596030/prices-html

Answer (score 1):

2x cards with dual DVI outputs will only depend on what kind of monitors you will be getting, keep in mind that you choose a card with a supported chipset by the drivers.

---

For information on the support for ATI chipsets use [this link](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Hardware).

---

For information on the support for NVidia chipsets use [this link](http://www.nvidia.com/object/linux-display-ia32-285.05.09-driver.html) and click on the *Supported Products* link.